# deja-dup: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, 17.10, backup, deja-dup

On Ubuntu 17.10, the Backups application fails with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1546, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1540, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1391, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1416, in do_backup
    globals.archive_dir).set_values()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

I think this might be a Python 2/3 problem, but it appears other users on 17.10 have deja-dup working.

I've tried reinstalling deja-dup and duplicity, same problem.

Duplicity version: 0.7.12-1ubuntu1
Deja-dup version: 36.3-0ubuntu0.1

**Edits:**

I was suspecting that for some reason Duplicity wasn't passing `self` to the class, but in the code the offending line is:

```
col_stats = collections.CollectionsStatus(globals.backend,
globals.archive_dir).set_values()
```

Meaning that it's probably not a Python version error because it did indeed pass three arguments to the class.

Now in the `CollectionsStatus` class, the help says:

```
Help on class CollectionsStatus in module duplicity.collections:

class CollectionsStatus
 |  Hold information about available chains and sets
 |
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
 |  __init__(self, backend, archive_dir, action)
 |      Make new object.  Does not set values
```

Meaning that it should definitely be passing 4 arguments, including `self`.

I have a feeling I know what's going wrong. I often use a script to update all of my Python modules, so I bet that class got changed somewhere along the line and the versions of Duplicity (the shell script) and its Python module are mismatched.

Comment: Did you install some version of Python manually?

Comment: @muru not that I remember ... `aptitude show python python3` says my Python versions are 2.7.14-2ubuntu1 and 3.6.3-0ubuntu2. Maybe I should try to find deja-dup's source and check if it's targeting a specific version of Python that's bugged, since those two are working fine.

Comment: `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py` shows `CollectionsStatus.__init__` actually takes 3 arguments as expected.

Comment: @muru Ah, I just finished writing up something about that in my edits section. I guess I'll have to downgrade the Python module of Duplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I had Duplicity Python module 0.7.14 and the aptitude package 0.7.12. I used `sudo pip uninistall duplicity`, followed by `sudo aptitude reinstall duplicity` and the problem's solved.

I guess I shouldn't be updating all of my Python modules at once.